# Skip a form step programmatically in simple_multistep module

Tags: 8, forms

I am trying to skip a step in multistep node form using [Simple Multistep](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_multistep) module. I have tried following snippet that works pretty good to skip one step.

```
$skipStep = $form_state->get('multistep_controller');
$skipStep->increaseStep();
$form_state->setRebuild();
```

**However, it has a problem click on back button it doesn't come back**.

I have search a lot but no luck, do anyone have idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by using **reduceStep()** method to come back.

```
$skipStep->reduceStep();
$form_state->set('multistep_controller', $skipStep);
$form_state->setRebuild();
```

Hope this would help someone.